# Quartz Scehduler 1.8.6 is executing twice in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

1. When my cron job runs the method is invoked twice.
2. Given below is the web.xml file.

### This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>uinvoiceUI</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml 
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
    <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/access_denied.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/400.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
    <locenter code hereation>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/403.jsp</location>
  </error-page>   

  <session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

3. The method is invoked properly, and the functionality is also working.
4. The thing is the method is invoked twice within just fraction of seconds.
5. The quartz is configured in the beans.xml file and from there it calls a method, and the method is executed.
6. I have found on the other links that contextLoaderListener is invoking the method once and once the quartz is running.
7. But I cannot rule out the contextLoaderListener from the web.xml.
8. If I do so the application wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that particular cron job is present (configured accidently) both in application context and servlet context. Resulting in duplicate invocation.